# How to access camera in same screen using phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova

I want to know that if it is possible to access camera in same webpage rather than opening native camera app.If yes then how can we do this ?

Thanx in advance...

Comment: You'd probably have to create your own plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a plugin as suggested by Drew, or you can rely on HTML5, but in that case I do not think it will work very well for old versions of android (let's say older than 4.0).

You can have a look at Raymond Camden's blog for more information : http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap (should work also in a phonegap app)